# Re-installing Virtualbox - unmet dependancies/broken packages?

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, virtualbox

I am struggeling a bit at the moment when it comes to upgrading Virtualbox - I have just removed the 5.2 package with apt (I am running Debian testing) and tried to reinstall it - I am constantly getting dependancy issues that I cannot resolve:

```
root@debian:/home/nomax# apt install virtualbox-5.2 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-5.2 : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libvpx4 (>= 1.6.0) but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: linux-image but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@debian:/home/nomax#
```

Anyone encountering this issue currently with the most recent Virtualbox version?

EDIT:

`root@debian:/# cat /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb xxxx://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free

# replacement of debian main mirror as checked against netselect-apt

# deb xxxx://mirror.intergrid.com.au/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb xxxx://mirror.amaze.com.au/debian/ testing main contrib non-free

# deb-src xxxx://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free

deb xxxx://security.debian.org/debian-security testing/updates main contrib non-free
# deb-src xxxx://security.debian.org/debian-security testing/updates main contrib non-free

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb xxxx://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free

# deb-src xxxx://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free
```

`root@debian:/# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`:

```
deb [arch=amd64] xxxxs://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] xxxxs://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable

deb [arch=amd64] xxxxs://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] xxxxs://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable

### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
# deb [arch=amd64] xxxx://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
# deb [arch=amd64] xxxx://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] xxxx://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] xxxx://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
# Kubernetes Repo on Google
deb xxxx://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
# Kubernetes Repo on Google
deb xxxx://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
#deb xxxx://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
deb xxxx://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
deb xxxx://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org sid main
deb-src xxxx://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org sid main
deb xxxx://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org tor-experimental-0.3.4.x-sid main
deb-src xxxx://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org tor-experimental-0.3.4.x-sid main
deb xxxx://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org sid main
deb-src xxxx://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org sid main
deb xxxx://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org tor-experimental-0.3.4.x-sid main
deb-src xxxx://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org tor-experimental-0.3.4.x-sid main
# virtualbox official Oracle repository
deb xxxx://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian stretch contrib
# virtualbox official Oracle repository
deb xxxx://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian stretch contrib
```

Comment: I had the feeling you were using vbox Ubuntu version until you mentioned testing. IMO, that is somewhat expected behaviour with testing.

Comment: Welcome, could you [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/464249/edit) by adding the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

Comment: Thanks, have edited - please excuse the many xxxxs, could not post otherwise my sources.lists :). Thanks!

Comment: 1) The kubernetes documentation say that the Xenial repo should be used on debian 9... 2)You don't need to add a third party repo to install virtualbox 5.2 on debian Testing beacuse it is available from `contrib`. Tor repo is available for debian Testing (Buster). Disable all Sid + Stretch repo then do `apt update && apt dist-upgrade` finally run `apt autoremove && apt install virtualbox`

Answer (score 1):

There is a known problem with installing the virtualbox-5.2 binary on Debian testing.

See this [Virutalbox forum thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=88757&hilit=debian+libcurl3).

To summarize, the Debian Stretch build which you are trying to install does not work on Debian testing because the former depends on libcurl3, while Debian testing now uses libcurl4.

Their suggested solution is to manually install the Ubuntu 18.04 package of virtualbox [(repo)](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/pool/contrib/v/virtualbox-5.2/): [virtualbox-5.2_5.2.18-124319~Ubuntu~bionic_amd64.deb](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/pool/contrib/v/virtualbox-5.2/virtualbox-5.2_5.2.18-124319~Ubuntu~bionic_amd64.deb). I have not personally tried doing so, and am still using an older version (5.2.14) on my Debian testing system. If you do install the the above, please let us if it works for you, as others will be curious.

An alternative is to install the Debian testing package for virutalbox from Debian's contrib repository. It looks like you already have the contrib repository setup in your sources.list. You should be able to see it with `apt-policy cache virtualbox` and install it with `apt install virtualbox`. Note the lack of `-5.2`.

Comment: Thanks gents (assumed gents :-))! It did the trick, I did follow GAD3R's mini-tut ran into other dependancy issues unfortunately, but i could resolve them in the end with apt --fix-broken install luckily. In the end I have now install virtualbox from the testing repo - it's the newer version 5.2.18 which you are referring to (and on my sys is now libcurl4 deployed).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into it too :-(

Recently I upgraded my workstation to  Devuan beowulf  and after done I lost
my virtualbox environment

kernel:  Linux version 4.19.0-13-686-pae

Scanning Internet solutions but none worked...

After a couple of failed attempts I succeeded by creating a new directory
/usr/local/preload/virtbox. Adding some files in it and changing things in
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/

adding:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1413564 Jan 27 19:05 libcrypto.so.0.9.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Jan 27 18:37 libcurl3.so -> libcurl.so.4.2.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Jan 27 18:49 libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.2.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  367476 Jan 27 18:36 libcurl.so.4.2.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  310992 Jan 27 19:01 libssl.so.0.9.8

renaming and symbolic linking:

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 Feb 22  2020 _libcurl-gnutls.so.3 -> libcurl-gnutls.so.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 Feb 22  2020 libcurl-gnutls.so.4 -> libcurl-gnutls.so.4.5.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 640596 Feb 22  2020 libcurl-gnutls.so.4.5.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Jan 27 18:52 _libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.5.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     39 Jan 27 21:32 libcurl.so.4 -> /usr/local/preload/virtbox/libcurl.so.4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 656988 Feb 22  2020 _libcurl.so.4.5.0
```

running ldconfig goes normal.

The directory name preload came because initially I thought to solve it with
LD_PRELOAD but that worked only partially.

The final solution came when I could lift old libraries from my firewall box
(debian squeeze) to /usr/local/preload/virtbox. After some fiddling with symbolic links and rename of the original library I could do

dpkg -i virtualbox-5.2_5.2.42-137960~Debian~stretch_i386.deb

without any error and I could run it again :-)

Kees